# How to display data from zoom poll results file?

Tags: excel, csv

I'm trying to figure out how to display the poll results from recent zoom meetings. The way zoom exports the data is something like this (.csv format):

```
Participant     Question            Answer
0001            Favorite Color?     Red
0002            Favorite Color?     Yellow
0003            Favorite Color?     Red;Blue
0004            Favorite Color?     Green;Blue;Red
0001            Favorite Season?    Fall;Summer
0002            Favorite Season?    Summer
0003            Favorite Season?    Spring;Summer
0004            Favorite Season?    Summer
0001            Are You Happy?      Yes
0002            Are You Happy?      Yes
0003            Are You Happy?      No
0004            Are You Happy?      Yes
```

So, depending on the poll question, you could have multiple answers on the same row.

My end goal is to display something like this:

```
Favorite Color?
  Red: 3
  Blue: 2
  Yellow: 1
  Green: 1

Favorite Season?
  Summer: 4
  Spring: 1
  Fall: 1

Are You Happy?
  Yes: 3
  No: 1
```

Comment: `=COUNTIF($E$2:$E$5,"*" & B2 & "*")` if the color name is in B2 and the Answers in (e.g.) E2:E5  Then fill down for other colors in B3, B4, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that there are multiple questions per file, with multiple answers. I'll edit my original post to show what I mean. Does your solution still work?

Comment: Yes if all the choices are unique and you have a list of them.

Comment: I won't have a list of them and all the answers won't be unique. I'll edit the original post again to make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For big data analysis, you can record a macro on sample data. Or you can use sumifs like in the formula bar of the screen shot

```
=SUMIFS($G$8:$G$11,$F$8:$F$11,"*"&E22&"*")
```

[image]

### EDIT:

Suggestion for big data: Text to columns first then Pivot will help avoid further calculations

[image]

Comment: Tim Williams has almost answered the question in his comment on the question. The only difference here is removing duplicates using pivot and text to column for finding values like "Green" and "Blue" which don't have individual cells. This will be useful for large number of rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And yes, this is for 2150 rows, so doing it manually would take a very long time. Ok, so I got the top 3 sections complete with all my data. I'm not really sure how to get the bottom section. Do I have to manually search through all the answers and list them in a column like how you have them? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I have a better suggestion. If you have similar data, as in the question. you can use text to column on the answer column. Then it would be easy for you to convert the additional columns created (like yellow in my Answer) to rows. Updating my answer.

Comment: Yea, that's what I ended up doing. Text to columns and then sorted A->Z each column while copy/pasting them below the original answer column. Thanks for your help!